# Change screen brightness in Windows Server 2019

Tags: intel-graphics, windows-server, windows-server-2019

My computer needs Display Enhancement Service to change the screen brightness, but this does not exist on Server 2019.

I tried to clone Microsoft.Graphics.Display.DisplayEnhancementService.dll from Windows 10 and add the service through the registry but it does not work.

I also tried to install the latest driver but it does not work.